# C# Console Calculator No overload for method take 0 arguement

Tags: c#, methods, console-application, calculator

I have no idea how to use methods in my calculator app. What's wrong with my method?
I write this 4 Calculator separately but have no idea ho to use methods to combine it together.

This Calculator will permit the user to choose from the following main menu:

1. Length calculator
2. Body Mass Index calculator
3. Waist to Height calculator
4. Fuel Consumption calculator
5. Exit the calculator

My current code has 4 errors said that:

> No overload for method 'BMICalculator' takes 0 arguments
>   No overload for method 'FuelConsumptionCalculator' takes 0 arguments
>   No overload for method 'LengthCalculator' takes 0 arguments 
>   No overload for method 'WaistToHeightCalculator' takes 0 argument

What am i missing??

My Current Code:

```
        static void LengthCalculator(string[] args) {

        double Centimetres = 0.0, Feet = 0.0, Inches = 0.0;
        string AnotherConversion = null;
        string LengthCalculatorMenu;
        int LengthCalculatorOption;

        do {
            LengthCalculatorMenu = ("Enter 1) Convert centimetres to feet and inches:"
                                 + "\nEnter 2) Convert feet and inches to centimetres:");
            Console.Write(LengthCalculatorMenu);
            LengthCalculatorOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (LengthCalculatorOption == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Centimetres(cm) that you wish to convert to feet and inches");
                Centimetres = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Feet = (Centimetres / 2.54) / 12;
                int iFeet = (int)Feet;
                Inches = (Feet - (double)iFeet) * 12;
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe equivalent in feet and inches is {0:G1} ft {1:G1} ins", Feet, Inches);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();
            } else if (LengthCalculatorOption == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Feet");
                Feet = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Inches");
                Inches = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Centimetres = ((Feet * 12) + Inches) * 2.54;
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe equivalent in centimetres is {0:G}cm", Centimetres);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while (AnotherConversion == "y" || AnotherConversion == "Y");
    }

    static void BMICalculator(string[] args) {

        double WeightKg = 0.0, HeightCm = 0.0, Weightlbs = 0.0, WeightOz = 0.0, BMI = 0.0, Feet = 0.0, Inches = 0.0;
        int BMIOption;
        string again = null;

        do {
            string BMIMenu = ("Which Measurement You Want to use to enter the weight and height?"
                            + "\n1)Enter 1 for Metric"
                            + "\n2)Enter 2 for British Imperial:");
            Console.Write(BMIMenu);
            BMIOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (BMIOption == 1) {
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Weight in Kilogram (kg):");
                WeightKg = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Height in in centimetres (cm):");
                HeightCm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                BMI = WeightKg / (HeightCm / 100 * HeightCm / 100);

                if (BMI >= 35.0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:G},Severe Obesity", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 30.0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:G},Obese", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 25.0) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:G},OverWeight", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 18.5) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:G},Healthy BodyWeight", BMI);
                } else if (BMI <= 18.5) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nYour BMI is {0:G},UnderWeight", BMI);
                }//End if
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                again = Console.ReadLine();

            } else if (BMIOption == 2) {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Weight in Pounds (lbs):");
                Weightlbs = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Weight in Ounces (oz):");
                WeightOz = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Height in Feet (ft):");
                Feet = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your Height in Inches (ins):");
                Inches = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                WeightKg = ((Weightlbs * 16) + WeightOz) / 35.2;
                HeightCm = ((Feet * 12) + Inches) * 2.54;
                BMI = WeightKg / (HeightCm / 100 * HeightCm / 100);

                if (BMI >= 35) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0:G},Severe Obesity", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 30) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0:G},Obese", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 25) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0:G},OverWeight", BMI);
                } else if (BMI >= 18.5) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0:G},Healthy BodyWeight", BMI);
                } else if (BMI <= 18.5) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is {0:G},UnderWeight", BMI);
                }//End if
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to make an another conversion? \n\n(Enter Y to make an another conversion/Enter any other key to exit):");
                again = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while (again == "y" || again == "Y");
    }


    static void WaistToHeightCalculator(string[] args) {

        int WaistToHeightCalculatorOption;
        int GenderOption;
        string AnotherConversion = null;
        double HeightCm = 0.0, WaistCm = 0.0;
        double WaistToHeightRatio = 0.0;
        double WaistIns = 0.0, HeightFeet = 0.0, HeightIns = 0.0, HeightTotalInIns = 0.0;

        do {
            string WaistToHeightCalculatorMenu = ("\nWhich Measurement You Want to use to enter the weight and height?"
                                               + "\n1)Enter 1 for Metric"
                                               + "\n2)Enter 2 for British Imperial:");
            Console.Write(WaistToHeightCalculatorMenu);
            WaistToHeightCalculatorOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (WaistToHeightCalculatorOption == 1) {

                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Height in cm:");
                HeightCm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter your Waist in centimetres (cm):");
                WaistCm = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                WaistToHeightRatio = WaistCm / HeightCm;
                Console.Write("\n1)Enter 1 If you are Male"
                            + "\n2)Enter 2 If you are Female:");
                GenderOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (GenderOption == 1 && WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.536) {
                    Console.Write("\nYour Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 1 && WaistToHeightRatio < 0.536) {
                    Console.Write("\nYour Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 2 && WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("\nYour Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 2 && WaistToHeightRatio < 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("\nYour Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } //End if

                Console.Write("\n\nWhould you like to make an anothe conversion? /n/n Enter Y to make an another conversion/Ener any other key to exit:");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();


            } else if (WaistToHeightCalculatorOption == 2) {
                Console.Write("\nPlase Enter your Waist in inches:");
                WaistIns = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter the Height in feet:");
                HeightFeet = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter the Heigt in inches:");
                HeightIns = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                WaistToHeightRatio = WaistIns / HeightTotalInIns;
                HeightTotalInIns = (HeightFeet * 12) + HeightIns;
                Console.Write("\nMale Enter 1 , Female Enter 2:");
                GenderOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (GenderOption == 1 && WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.536) {
                    Console.Write("Your Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 1 && WaistToHeightRatio < 0.536) {
                    Console.Write("Your Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 2 && WaistToHeightRatio >= 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("Your Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at High Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } else if (GenderOption == 2 && WaistToHeightRatio < 0.492) {
                    Console.Write("Your Waist to Height Ration is {0}, Your Risk of Obesity Related Cardiovascular Diseases is at low Risk", WaistToHeightRatio);
                } //End if
                Console.Write("\n\nWhould you like to make an anothe conversion? /n/n Enter Y to make an another conversion/Ener any other key to exit:");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while (AnotherConversion == "Y" || AnotherConversion == "y");
    }

    static void FuelConsumptionCalculator(string[] args) {

        int FuelConsumptionMenuOption;
        double Litre = 0.0, Kilometre = 0.0, Gallon = 0.0, Mile = 0.0;
        double ComsumptionPer100Km = 0.0, ComsumptionPer100KmInMPG = 0.0, ComsumptionPer100KmInKm = 0.0, ComsumptionPerGal = 0.0;
        ComsumptionPer100KmInMPG = ((Kilometre / 1.609) / (Litre / 4.546)) * 100;
        string ToSeeMPerGalOption, ToSeelPerKmOption;
        string AnotherConversion;
        do {
            string FuelConsumptionMenu = ("\nWhich Measurement You Want to use to enter the weight and height?"
                                                   + "\n1)Enter 1 for Metric"
                                                   + "\n2)Enter 2 for British Imperial:");
            Console.Write(FuelConsumptionMenu);
            FuelConsumptionMenuOption = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (FuelConsumptionMenuOption == 1) {
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter Litres(l) of Fuel used over distance travelled:");
                Litre = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter Kilometres driven:");
                Kilometre = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                ComsumptionPer100Km = Litre / (Kilometre / 100);
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour Consumption in Litres per 100 Kilometres is {0}", ComsumptionPer100Km);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to see the equivalent result in miles per gallon (mpg)?"
                                 + "\n(Press Y For yes or Press other key to cancel this option):");
                ToSeeMPerGalOption = Console.ReadLine();
                ComsumptionPer100KmInMPG = ((Kilometre / 1.609) / (Litre / 4.546) * 100);

                if (ToSeeMPerGalOption == "Y" || ToSeeMPerGalOption == "y") {
                    Console.Write("\nThe equivalent result in miles per gallon (mpg) is {0}", ComsumptionPer100KmInMPG);
                }
                Console.Write("\n\nWhould you like to make an anothe conversion? /n/n Enter Y to make an another conversion/Ener any other key to exit:");
                AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();

            } else if (FuelConsumptionMenuOption == 2) {
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter Gallons (gal) of Fuel used over distance travelled:");
                Gallon = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("\nPlease Enter Miles (m)driven:");
                Mile = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                ComsumptionPerGal = Gallon / Mile;
                Console.WriteLine("\nYour Consumption in Miles per Gallon is {0}", ComsumptionPerGal);
                Console.Write("\nWould you like to see the equivalent result in litres per 100 kilometres(km)?"
                                 + "\n(Press Y For yes or Press other key to cancel this option):");
                ToSeelPerKmOption = Console.ReadLine();
                ComsumptionPer100KmInKm = ((Mile * 1.609) / (Gallon * 4.546)) * 100;

                if (ToSeelPerKmOption == "Y" || ToSeelPerKmOption == "y") {
                    Console.Write("\nThe equivalent result in litres per 100 kilometres(km) is {0}", ComsumptionPer100KmInKm);
                }
            }//End if 
            Console.Write("\n\nWhould you like to make an anothe conversion? /n/n Enter Y to make an another conversion/Ener any other key to exit:");
            AnotherConversion = Console.ReadLine();

        } while (AnotherConversion == "Y" || AnotherConversion == "y");

    }

    static int ReadOption() {
        int option =0 ;
        bool ValidMainMenuOption = false;

    do{
       option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

       if ((1 <=option) & (option <= 5)) {
           ValidMainMenuOption = true ;
       } else {
           ValidMainMenuOption = false;
       } // end if

       if (!ValidMainMenuOption){
           Console.WriteLine("\n\t\a Option must be 1,2,3,4,5");
           DisplayMenu();
       } //end if 
     } while (!ValidMainMenuOption);

    return option;
    } //end ReadOption

    /* Displays Main Menu
     * Precondition:true
     * postcondition: mainMenu displayed
     */
    static void DisplayMenu() {
        string mainMenu = "\n1)Length Calculator"
                        + "\n2)Body Mass Index Calculator"
                        + "\n3)Waist to Height Calculator"
                        + "\n4)Fuel Consumption Calculator"
                        + "\n5)Exit the Calculator"
                        + "\n\n Enter your option(1,2,3,4 or 5 to exit):";
        Console.Write(mainMenu);
    } //end mainMenu

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int Exit = 5;
        int menuOption = ReadOption();

        do {
            DisplayMenu();

            if (menuOption == 1) {
                LengthCalculator();
            } else if (menuOption == 2) {
                BMICalculator();
            } else if (menuOption == 3) {
                WaistToHeightCalculator();
            } else if (menuOption == 4) {
                FuelConsumptionCalculator();
            } else if (menuOption == 5) {
                Console.Write("Thank you for using this Calculator, See you next time");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to Exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            } 

        } while (menuOption != Exit);

        // need to output terminating message 
        Console.ReadKey();

    } //end Main
```

Comment: Did you really have to post every single line of that code? Really? If you had left out a single line, you don't think we could have helped you?

Comment: All that means is that you are calling `BMICalculator` and others but not passing in a parameter.

Comment: opps sorry about that

Comment: @user3448746 - you have nothing to be sorry about

Answer (score 2):

Your function is defined as

```
static void WaistToHeightCalculator(string[] args)
```

you are calling it like this

```
WaistToHeightCalculator();
```

you need to call it like this

```
WaistToHeightCalculator(args);
```

You must pass all arguments that a function is defined to take. I am assuming you wrote each one of these as main and then tried to pull them all together. The error `No overload for method 'BMICalculator' takes 0 arguments` simply means the complier could not find a version of that function that takes no arguments. It know only of the version with one argument which is an array of strings.

### edit

As @jdpenix says you also don't use args in any of the functions so you could change the functions definitions to `static void  WaistToHeightCalculator()` and continue calling them the way you are.

Comment: It's also reasonable to propose changing the method sigatures to `WaistToHeightCalculator()`, because `args` is never used in _any_ of them.

Comment: @jdphenix - but what about `snip for brevity` we don't know what the op is doing

Comment: Thank you. Now I want to ask when to use void and when to use value returning?

Comment: @user3448746  use void when you don't want to return a value

Answer (score 0):

```
My Current Code:
static void LengthCalculator(string[] args) {
// snip for brevity
}

static void BMICalculator(string[] args) {
// snip for brevity
}

static void WaistToHeightCalculator(string[] args) {
// snip for brevity
}

static void FuelConsumptionCalculator(string[] args) {
// snip for brevity
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
const int Exit = 5;
int menuOption = ReadOption();

do {
    DisplayMenu();

    if (menuOption == 1) {///////////////////////////////////////////////////
        LengthCalculator(args); // <------HERE
    } else if (menuOption == 2) {
        BMICalculator(args); // <------HERE
    } else if (menuOption == 3) {
        WaistToHeightCalculator(args); // <------HERE
    } else if (menuOption == 4) {
        FuelConsumptionCalculator(args); // <------HERE
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    } else if (menuOption == 5) {
        Console.Write("Thank you for using this Calculator, See you next time");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any Key to Exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    } 

} while (menuOption != Exit);

// need to output terminating message 
Console.ReadKey();

} //end Main
```